# File is not moving in directory in lumen

Tags: php, file, file-upload, lumen

I am trying to store a file in the following path "public/uploads/images" with lumen.
Here is my code

```
if($request->hasFile('photo')){
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $fileName = time().$counter.'.'.$request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file('photo')->move('/uploads/images', $fileName);
    return $fileName;
}
```

But no file is moving to the path. only the file name is returned. What is the problem and how to solve?

Answer (score -1):

try to use the public_path function to upload it into public folder.
Example:

```
$request->file('photo')->move(public_path("/uploads"), $newfilename);
```

Visit https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-upload-using-storage-function-to-public-folder

Comment: ReflectionException
Class filesystem does not exist